# Are static and relative with no other attributes always rendered in the same place?

Tags: html, positioning, css

I understand that an element with position relative will be used as the fixed for elements inside it with positioning absolute, and that with relative I can *push* the element around, but if I don't add any other attributes, will an element with this style:

```
.element1 {
   position: relative;
}
```

always render the same as one with:

```
.element2 {
  position: static;
}
```

If not, when would they differ?

Answer (score 3):

It will appear same because you are saying that I am going to position you and not instructing where to position so unless you position it will remain at same place.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a wiki entry dealing exactly with this topic:

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_static_and_relative_positioning

According to this, it makes only a difference, if there is also some positioning, as you said, and other elements around, which might then be overlapped by your relative positioned one.